# Failing to start systemd service

Tags: linux, systemd

I have written the following systemd service to login at the wireless at boot:

```
[Unit]
Description=Wireless network connectivity (%i)
Wants=network.target
Before=network.target
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i-device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i-device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

ExecStart=/usr/bin/ip link set dev %i up
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wpa_supplicant -B -i %i -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dhcpcd %i

ExecStop=/usr/bin/ip link set dev %i down

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I then `enable` it but I get the following error every time I boot my computer:

```
[abc@arch ~]$ systemctl --failed
  UNIT                            LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● network-wireless@wlp3s0.service loaded failed failed Wireless network connectivity (wlp3s0)
```

However if I manually start this service after boot with:

```
systemctl start network-wireless@xlp3s0
```

the service starts as expected.

This is the content of wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
network={
        ssid="TeliaGateway30-91-8F-1C-B2-29"
        #psk="A80871A90A"
        psk=b4d8a1e9ad665eed0178fea6f141134e795e15183a661848b371a41bb73a6844
}
```

Why is this services starting ok when starting it manually but not at boot and how can I change it to start at boot?

EDIT: Added error output:
This is what error im getting:

```
[abc@arch ~]$ journalctl -b -u network-wireless@wlp3s0.service
-- Logs begin at Sat 2015-08-22 12:50:42 CEST, end at Sun 2015-08-23 22:15:26 CEST. --
Aug 23 21:23:36 arch systemd[1]: Starting Wireless network connectivity (wlp3s0)...
Aug 23 21:23:36 arch ip[274]: Cannot find device "wlp3s0"
Aug 23 21:23:36 arch systemd[1]: network-wireless@wlp3s0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 23 21:23:36 arch systemd[1]: Failed to start Wireless network connectivity (wlp3s0).
Aug 23 21:23:37 arch systemd[1]: network-wireless@wlp3s0.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 23 21:23:37 arch systemd[1]: network-wireless@wlp3s0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 21:25:11 arch systemd[1]: Starting Wireless network connectivity (wlp3s0)...
Aug 23 21:25:11 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: waiting for carrier
Aug 23 21:25:16 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: carrier acquired
Aug 23 21:25:16 arch dhcpcd[424]: DUID 00:01:00:01:1d:6b:6b:e6:10:0d:7f:b7:30:f3
Aug 23 21:25:16 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: IAID c1:c4:73:e0
Aug 23 21:25:16 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Aug 23 21:25:16 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.85
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: leased 192.168.1.85 for 3600 seconds
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: adding default route via 192.168.1.1
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: forked to background, child pid 477
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: waiting for carrier
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: carrier acquired
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: DUID 00:01:00:01:1d:6b:6b:e6:10:0d:7f:b7:30:f3
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: IAID c1:c4:73:e0
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.85
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: leased 192.168.1.85 for 3600 seconds
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: wlp3s0: adding default route via 192.168.1.1
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch dhcpcd[424]: forked to background, child pid 477
Aug 23 21:25:21 arch systemd[1]: Started Wireless network connectivity (wlp3s0).
Aug 23 21:25:28 arch dhcpcd[477]: wlp3s0: no IPv6 Routers available
Aug 23 22:15:09 arch dhcpcd[477]: wlp3s0: carrier lost
Aug 23 22:15:09 arch dhcpcd[477]: wlp3s0: deleting route to 192.168.1.0/24
Aug 23 22:15:09 arch dhcpcd[477]: wlp3s0: deleting default route via 192.168.1.1
Aug 23 22:15:13 arch dhcpcd[477]: wlp3s0: carrier acquired
Aug 23 22:15:14 arch dhcpcd[477]: wlp3s0: IAID c1:c4:73:e0
Aug 23 22:15:14 arch dhcpcd[477]: wlp3s0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Aug 23 22:15:14 arch dhcpcd[477]: wlp3s0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.85
Aug 23 22:15:19 arch dhcpcd[477]: wlp3s0: leased 192.168.1.85 for 3600 seconds
Aug 23 22:15:19 arch dhcpcd[477]: wlp3s0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
Aug 23 22:15:19 arch dhcpcd[477]: wlp3s0: adding default route via 192.168.1.1
Aug 23 22:15:19 arch dhcpcd[477]: wlp3s0: removing route to 192.168.1.0/24
Aug 23 22:15:26 arch dhcpcd[477]: wlp3s0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

EDIT:
I have found one potetential error, it seems as if the network interface changes name from wlan0 during boot, however i have tried starting the service with wlan0 but with no change in the result.

Comment: What errors is systemd reporting for the service?

Comment: How can i check that?

Comment: Try running: `systemctl status network-wireless@wlp3s0.service` or `journalctl -b`

Comment: Or better yet, `journalctl -b -u network-wireless@wlp3s0.service`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the service stops at boot is because the `ip` command cannot find the interface. According to the man page for [systemd services](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=) that is enough reason to fail the service.

As you noticed yourself the interface gets renamed or is not ready yet at boot.

- You can check if you need to add an `After=` statement
- You can check with the `systemd-analyze` command if the ordering at boot is correct
- You could split up the service and make it more robust. Most daemons can start fine even if the interface is not ready yet.

Personally I would make dhcpd and wpa_supplicant separate services and use systemd's networkd or an udev rule to bring up the interface (if that is even needed). There are a lot examples of unit files for `wpa_supplicant` and `dhcpd` online maybe have look at those?